# python error in import

Tags: python

In a vartual env `taxenv` when I try to run my python program `runner.py` it shows the following error

[image]

The first line of my `runner.py` is

```
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
```

what to do? How do I install `openpyxl` in the virtual env?

I've tried `pip install openpyxl in the virtualenv`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install it using pip:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Optionally specify a `requirements.txt` to specify the dependencies. Read more about it [here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/1.1/requirements.html).

Comment: when I do `pip install openpyxl` it's giving another error as shown above

Comment: Maybe you need to upgrade `pip` or `setuptools` first using `pip install pip setuptools --upgrade`.